# EF Migrations not able to remove migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

**Edit:** I dropped the database. *It still tells me the migration is applied.* I don't buy your shit, EF...

I have 5 migrations, but the 5th has been created on accident. It doesn't hold any changes (`Up` and `Down` methods are empty). Without thinking I appied it to the database.

Now when I run `dotnet ef database update migration4` it tells me it successfully reverted migration #5 and the table `__EFMigrationsHistory` doesn't show an entry for migration #5. Upon trying to remove it with `dotnet ef migrations remove` it tells me that migration #5 is still applied to the database and the entry in `__EFMigrationsHistory` shows back up.

When rolling back to migration #3 with `dotnet ef database update migration3` it does remove the changes from migration #4, and removes the entries from the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table.

Now, when trying to remove, *it just reapplies all the migrations*. Same for reverting back to initial migration.

Any suggestions? I have no idea where to begin. Do I have to redo the whole database and/or migrations? I tried overriding migration #5 but `dotnet ef migrations add` doesn't accept the parameters `-f` or `--force`.

Comment: you can remove the migration one by one from the last. So you first remove 5 then 4 then 3

Comment: `dotnet ef database update migration3` wont remove the changes from migration3. It will remove from migration4

Comment: Have you tried using Package Manager Console? I use the command `Update-database -TargetMigration:"Migrationx" -force` which works successfully

Comment: Package manager console also runs the same command internally

Comment: @viveknuna what would removing the migrations one by one accomplish that running `database update migration1` would not? I was wrong about it not reverting the changes, rather it re-applies them when trying to remove migration #5

Comment: @PeterSmith i'm trying to force the `migrations add` command to override migration #5, updating the database works without issue

Comment: Sorry, should have said that you can also you that to rewind - in your case use `migration4`

Comment: @PeterSmith I've updated my post since at first I got wrong what happened myself - it updates (and downgrades) perfectly fine, but when I try to exectute `dotnet ef migrations remove`, that's when it applies all the older migrations again and tells me that it's unable to remove migration #5 - because it is for whatever reason applied again.

Comment: THIS WORKS FOR ME: You "should" be able to delete the MIGRATION #5 record from the DB (by hand or by restoring the previous)...and then....delete (by hand) the MIGRATION #5 file from your solution.  Of course, if there are "lingering" objects in your solution that are not part of MIGRATION 4...you will get a message prompting you of a pending migration.  So you need to remove those too (or create a new #5).

Answer (score 3):

the better way is 
go to

PM Remove-Migration

PM Drop-DataBase

or delete your migration folder in your solution explore and create a new migration 
this will make your all 5 migration into one migration

PM Add-Migration

PM Update-Database

Comment: I ended up using this approach - dropping the db, removing the migration (with `-f` since it still thought the migration had been applied to the db - _**which didn't exist at this point**_) and running `database update` to recreate the db with the new and proper migration applied. The drawback is: I lost all the data which I would have to recover or save in SQL scripts if this wasn't dev environment. That's also why I won't accept this answer.